# Is it possible to check if a PrismaClient instance is currently in a transaction?

Tags: prisma, prisma-transaction

To do an "interactive" transaction in Prisma, one writes:

```
prisa.$transaction(async (txnClient) => {

  // Write code that uses txnClient just like a non-transactional PrismaClient instance.
```

Given an instance of PrismaClient, is there a way to test if it's currently inside of a transaction (i.e. it's a `txnClient` from above)?

My use-case is to optionally share a transaction across two functions that both must wrap their own code in a transaction, e.g. each could look like:

```
function someWork(prisma: PrismaClient): Promise<unknown> {
  if (prisma.isAlreadyInTransaction) {
    // Do the work
  } else {
    // Start a transaction and then do the work
}
```

It does seem that the test `'$transaction' in prisma` would work, but is that official API or just coincidental?